# Java: How can I get generic type in runtime?

Tags: java, generics, runtime

```
Class clazz = parameter.getParameterType();
```

Here I have `clazz`, which i'm certain that this is `Optional<T>` type class. The problem is how can I get this `T`? I want to know if this is `String` or `Long` or `Integer` or something in the runtime.

ok, I think I didn't put it clearly. I got a method parameters by reflection,

```
public String abc(Optional<String> ttt, Optional<Integer> bbb) {
    return;
}
```

So now I have the class of ttt, and bbb, and i'm sure that this is `Optional<T>.class`, but can I get which `T` elasctly that is.

Comment: it's not `Optional<T>.class`, it's `Optional.class` for _both_ of them; _exactly the same_ `Optional.class`.

Comment: Possible of duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *cannot.*  At runtime, Java doesn't even know the actual generic type.

If the `Optional` is present, you can do `optional.get().getClass()`, but if the optional is absent there is absolutely no way to tell whether it is an `Optional<String>`, `Optional<Integer>`, or `Optional<NuclearMissile>`.